# Python send request POST header Authorization to clientside(vuejs)

Tags: python, vue.js, post, header, authorization

I am trying to make a POST request using python.

I want to pass json data with header, which contains `"Authorization": Bearer XXXXXX`

My code is below:

```
import requests
import json
access_token = 'xxxxxxxxx'
    payload = {'source': '0'}
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
        'user_id' : '2'
    }
    req = requests.Request('POST','https://otherdomain.com/add',headers=headers,data=json.dumps(payload))
    prepared = req.prepare()
    print(prepared)
    s = requests.Session()
    resp = s.send(prepared,verify=False)
    print(resp.headers)
```

I print header `prepared` have data as below:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxx',
'user_id' : '2'
'source': '0'
```

But, when I request POST to url `https://otherdomain.com/add`, I check in `inspect element chrome` (F12), don't have any header value (view attached image)

I don't know where I wrong, please help.

[Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY2Ea.png)

Comment: Not sure why you use Chrome to inspect a request sent in python

Comment: Because I send header from python to clientside (https://otherdomain.com/add). So I use Chrome inspect request header.

Comment: You can't send a request to client side. What is handling 'https://otherdomain.com/add' ?